# Upgraded from Vista to Windows 7 - Program files missing on start menu

Tags: windows-7

Just like the title says; upgraded from windows vista ultimate to windows 7. Now all the "program files" are missing when i click on start. Has anyone experienced this or offer some suggestions to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for a while the solution that worked for me was below.

Open C:\Users\ [...] \App Data\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu and right clicked on the programs folder, then properties. then i checked the 'hidden' check box to make the folder (and all subfolders) hidden. then click 'ok'.